# Select an option of a drop down list element on web page with vba Excel and submit the web form with the new value selected on the list

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer, html-lists

There is a non-public webpage where I want to fill and submit programatically all fields on it. I have no experience with web programming but I have even so been able to programming some simple web-scraping macros.

The drop down list on the web page looks like this:

[image: One of the drop down lists on web page]

When I inspect the drop down list, I can see the next html code: [image]

And next is what appear in the "Debugger" section:
[image]

I have tried something like this but it doesnt work, it simply does change nothing in the drop down list:

```
Set Item = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("rcbList")(1)
Set celem = Item.Children
For Each e In celem
    Debug.Print e.innerText
    If e.innerText = "Ground" Then
        o.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I also have tried somethig like this and it actually write "Ground" in the input field but when I submit the form web, the drop down list doesnt take the value I set.

```
Dim nodeDropDown As Object

Set nodeDropDown = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AppMethodRadCombobox_Input")
nodeDropDown.Value = "Ground"
```

Can you give me some hints about what can I do? Please let me know if any information is missing.

Comment: why o not e for click? Unlikely solution but does look like a logic error / typo